# In the context shown, what does "(+ 1 overload)" mean?

Tags: c#

Example code:

```
    protected void btn_Add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lst_Categories.Items.Insert(lst_Categories.Items.Count, txt_Input.Text);
    }
```

Image of context popup over the word "Insert":

[image]
In the popup shown (see image), of which the words in question is "(+ 1 overload)", what does this phrase mean?

Comment: It means that the Insert method has one more version (overload) that use a different set of parameters. You could see it pressing the down arrow key

Comment: @Steve--thanks, I was hovering the mouse over the word "Insert" and the context-sensitive popup showed up.  Pressing the down arrow key has no effect.

Comment: Uhm no, the context-sensitive popup doesn't take input. It is when you start typing after the _Insert(_ open braces that you can browse with up/down arrows the possible alternatives

Comment: Gotcha.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means there is one more method overload with same name but with different arguments. See more at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691131(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: This Insert method is used only once in my code.  Why would there be an apparently another method (hence overload)?

Comment: The Insert method belongs to some other class and this class has two Insert methods in it.

Comment: To check this, just right click on Insert and select "Go To Definition". You'll find there 2 Insert methods with different parameters.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Certainly explains it.